# File Input and Output using file access flags and c++

Tags: c++

Lets say I create a document on notepad named Numbers.txt. I place the number 6 on the notepad and close out. I then type the following code segment.

```
#include< iostream>
#include < fstream >

int main()    
{    
  fstream sample;

  sample.open("Numbers.txt", ios::in | ios :: out);

  if(sample)    
  {

     int number;
     sample >> number;
     sample << "555";
    sample.close();
   }
}
```

For reason sometimes it prints out 555 and sometimes it just prints out 6. There is no consistency.  In other words how exactly is the output being sent to the file. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: What do you mean by 'print out'? I don't see it printing out anything.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file for both input and output, you *must* do a `seek` when you switch between reading and writing that file. I'd cite the standard to show where, but the set of citations you need to quote gets fairly long (goes all the way to the C standard). Basically, it says that reading and writing are done as if they had used functions from the C library, and the C standard says you need to do a seek when switching between input and output on a stream that's opened for both.